# pickle unicode strings with non-ascii caracters to mysql in django

Tags: python, django, encoding, django-models, pickle

Consider the I have an dictionary that I want to store in db using python's pickle.

My question is: which django models' field should I use?

So far I've been using a CharField, but there seems to be an error:

I pickle a u'\xe9' (i.e. 'É'), and I get:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xE1, ist...' for column 'edition' at row 1
```

(the ,"ist..." was because I have more text after the 'É').

I'm using

```
data = dict();
data['foo'] = input_that_has_the_caracter
to_save_in_db = cPickle.dumps(data)
```

Should I use a binary field and pickle with a protocol that uses binary? Because I have to change the db in order to do that, so it is better to be sure first...

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are using a proper encoding for your table AND column in your database backend (I'm assuming MySQL since your error message seems to be from it). In MySQL columns can have different encoding than the table. See if it's UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks. However, that is the "MySQL" approach. I'm searching for the Django way, since it is not good idea to combine pure MySQL changes on tables without properly telling it to Django.

Comment: Your django code is fine (as far as using CharField for pickled data is concerned - you might want to add additional step to make sure you are converting "input_that_has_the_character" into unicode), it's just that your DB doesn't seem to be set up correctly. Your django code is passing unicode value into the database as it is supposed to, but your DB doesn't seem to be recognizing it. That's why you should check your DB setup.

Comment: I confirmed that changing the column to utf8 (utf8_swedish_ci) gives the same problem. :/

Comment: What happens if you set it to utf-8_general_ci?